# What's causing the Vue computed property to be computed?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

My understanding of computed properties is that if the computed property is not used in the template it's not supposed to be computed. However, when there is a watcher for a computed property, this computed property is evaluated.

I understand it's not desired application architecture, but my question is if the fact that it's working this way is a desired Vue behaviour or some side-effect of how things are implemented right now and can change in future releases?

Or to put the question in other words:
Should the computed property be evaluated if it's not used in the template and it has no other explicit getter in the codebase, except a watcher?

Example:

```
<template>
  <div>
        <button @click="counter++">+1</button>
        {{ counter }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Main",
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    notUsedInTemplate() {
      console.log("notUsedInTemplate computed called");
      return this.counter + 1;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    notUsedInTemplate() {
      console.log("notUsedInTemplate watch called");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/computed-sandbox-ru3n3?file=/src/components/Main.vue:0-818

Comment: form the logic you write in the computed property you could give it away and increase the counter by one from the `watch` object

Comment: The actual logic I have in my component is far more complex. The one from the question is just to better describe the problem. I know that it should be done in `watch` but this kind of refactor in real life is not something I can afford right now. I want to get more insight from the industry to know whether it's the desired behavior of Vue or something that may be gone in future releases. Based on this knowledge I can prioritize the refactor.

Comment: vue recommend using computed compare to watch. Possible reason can be performance, and declarative vs imperative, computed is easy to process and set compare to watch. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Could you explain why this is important for you to know? Everything you do in a computed property has to be side-effect free. So you must not set/modify any properties from within it (or call functions that might result in this) or use any non-local value that is not reactive  (one being `const` might be ok). Strictly speaking your `console.log("notUsedInTemplate computed called");` would also be a side effect. So from the perspective of the state of your values and from your app, it wouldn't make any difference if `watch` triggers the call to the computed property or not.

Comment: It's important for me to know because I prefer to understand the framework I work with and this behavior surprised me a lot. @michal-levý made a good point in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69173570/whats-causing-the-vue-computed-property-to-be-computed/69173816?noredirect=1#comment122262327_69174606) and after going through the Vue's codebase I understand why it's working this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*if the computed property is not used in the template it's not supposed to be computed*

...is not correct. Correct statement is:

*if the computed property is not used (anywhere) it's not supposed to be evaluated*

Using `watch` evaluates the property. In fact `watch` is very similar to template re-rendering (In vue 3 re-rendering is in fact little special [watchEffect](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watcheffect))

Because to watch (anything):

1. Vue 1st needs to run the code - in this case `notUsedInTemplate` getter - to find out what reactive data it is accessing (so `this.counter` is tracked as dependency)
2. When `this.counter` changes, watcher runs the `notUsedInTemplate` getter again so it can compare new value to previous one
3. If value changed, it runs the callback (which is logging in your example)

So to answer the questions:

1. yes this is desired behavior as your watcher is not tracking changes of `notUsedInTemplate` computed property but underlying data it uses to compute it's value
2. Watcher is accessing the  computed property, there is no need to use it anywhere else

### OK, more details WHY this works this way

Vue reactivity has always 2 phases:

1. phase 1 - run the code (be it template or [watch expression/fn](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)) and collect all dependencies (e.g. any reactive data the code "touched")
2. phase 2 - track the dependencies. If any dependency changes, re-run callback (or render function)

See this chapter in the docs - [How Changes Are Tracked](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked) - the example is explicitly mentioning only template re-rendering (which uses watcher created by Vue itself) but all of this applies to [all watchers](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0948d999f2fddf9f90991956493f976273c5da1f/src/core/observer/watcher.js#L87) including those created by the user

Comment: That the watcher initially asks for the current value is one way of targeting the problem in code. But technically it would also be possible to do it at the moment when the property changed. I was searching through the documentation and also the test cases to figure out where it is explained under which circumstances a computed property is called, and how the watcher exactly behaves. But I didn't find a clear answer to that. Please add references/citations of the particular parts in the documentation that verify your claims.

Comment: *But technically it would also be possible to do it at the moment when the property changed* ...well I don't think so. How would Vue know that the value of computed prop changed without running it 1st in the first place? Vue reactivity has always 2 phases - phase 1 - run the code (be it template or watch expression/fn) and collect all dependencies. phase 2 - track dependencies changes and re-run callback (or render function)

Comment: `How would Vue know that the value of computed prop changed without running it 1st in the first place?` Technically you could parse the code to find the dependent properties. There sure might be some problematic parts there, but I wouldn't say that it is completely impossible. But that does not really matter, the point is just because it is likely to be that way right now does not mean that it could not change. A guarantee that this behavior won't change is if it is specified that way in the documentation.

Comment: Vue documentation is good but it lacks lot of (arguably too technical) details. In this case the [code is documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0948d999f2fddf9f90991956493f976273c5da1f/src/core/observer/watcher.js#L87)

Comment: @MichalLevý your comment answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the computed property. Anything in the computed property will attach to `vue` instance and accessible in the template.

So, if it not used in template, it should not be in computed.

`computed` properties are declarative in where as `watch` is imperative.

```
computed: {
// a computed getter
reversedMessage: function () {
  // `this` points to the vm instance
  return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
 }
}
```

*And the best part is that we’ve created this dependency relationship declaratively: the computed getter function has no side effects, which makes it easier to test and understand.*

watch are functions that looks for changes and update the value.

```
watch: {
firstName: function (val) {
  this.fullName = val + ' ' + this.lastName
},
lastName: function (val) {
  this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + val
 }
}
```

By using computed getter property you are just making it easy for `vue` to track the changes and update in a declarative way, however you can do the same wit `watch` but it is imperative and vue need to look for changes and each changes required that function call to be trigger and later executing that function.

[more info](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Comment: "So, if it not used in template, it should not be in computed." - but it is. Is it a bug then? Or desired, but not perfect behavior?

Comment: It is not perfect behavior, you can created computed property but you are not using it for its primary use case.